# Variable Gain Amplifier (VGA) Cadence Simulation

Tags: power, amplifier, transient, cadence

I'm designing an Amplifier (VGA). I'm using Cadence CMOS 180nm technology. How can I find the power up time and power down time (1% of final current)?

Comment: Did you previously know how to use CADENCE simulation prior to designing the VGA?